# Django/ Heroku Deployment (ProgrammingError at / relation "posts_post" does not exist LINE 1)

Tags: django, heroku, django-models, heroku-postgres

I'm Sorry to ask again, but i haven't gotten any solutions. my django blog works fine locally but after deploying to heroku, i started having an error. Please what can I do to resolve this?
The error states: `"ProgrammingError at / relation "posts_post" does not exist LINE 1: ...evious_post_id", "posts_post"."next_post_id" FROM "posts_pos..."`

Comment: your error should be seen in full in the description formatted as code, and the title more simple.

Comment: Thank you......I've updated the question and i hope it's a bit clearer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have much details here, but relation does not exist means the table is not created.

So I suspect when deploying to heroku you created a new database but you haven't run the migrations for it.

So try to run the `python manage.py migrate` command on the heroku database.

Answer (score 0):

Open command line of heroku :
heroku run bash

Make migration of database :
py manage.py makemigrations

Migrate database :
py manage.py migrate

Create super user :
py manage.py createsuperuser

Login as admin at your hosted site:
https://website url/admin

This will not upload your data  at local server.

You may add data by creating superuser at heroku server